# Creating grid on exported canvas

Tags: pyqgis

By fetching the top left and bottom right coordinates, I am trying to create a grid over the selected polygon;

```
import os
import shapefile
import numpy as np

myfilepath = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()

shape = shapefile.Reader(myfilepath, encoding = "ISO8859-1")

feature = shape.shapeRecords()[0]

points = feature.shape.points
points = [list(i) for i in points]

poly_max = np.max(points, axis=0)
poly_min = np.min(points, axis=0)
poly = [poly_max[0], poly_max[1], poly_min[0], poly_min[1]]
```

Obviously `poly` prints the coordinates.

The following step is where it goes wrong and I'm not sure why:

```
processing.run("native:creategrid", {'TYPE':2,'EXTENT':poly+' [EPSG:5845]',
                                     'HSPACING':10,
                                     'VSPACING':14,
                                     'HOVERLAY':0,
                                     'VOVERLAY':0,
                                     'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:5845'),
                                     'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Am I right to conclude that it doesn't approve of using strings in the command? Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list with `poly = [poly_max[0], poly_max[1], poly_min[0], poly_min[1]]` and you cant concatenate a list with a string like you are doing with `poly+' [EPSG:5845]'`

Use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) when combining the variables.

```
src = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/12polygons.shp"
vl = QgsVectorLayer(src, "mylayer", "ogr")

#List all features and find the extents 
all_features = [f for f in vl.getFeatures()]

theone = all_features[0] #Select one
bbox = theone.geometry().boundingBox()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = bbox.xMinimum(), bbox.xMaximum(), bbox.yMinimum(), bbox.yMaximum()

#Create the grid.
#The extent parameter for the grid should be a string in this format: xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax [EPSG:XXXX]
    
extent = f"{xmin},{xmax},{ymin},{ymax} [{vl.crs().authid()}]"
grid = processing.run("native:creategrid", 
    {'TYPE':2,'EXTENT':extent,'HSPACING':1000,'VSPACING':1001,
    'HOVERLAY':0,'VOVERLAY':0,'CRS':vl.crs(),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(grid)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Poly is a list! And `' [EPSG:5845]'` is a string. How should a sum of this work?

Just try `'EXTENT': QgsRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out by replacing `'EXTENT':poly+' [EPSG:5845]',` with `'EXTENT':','.join(map(str, poly))+' [EPSG:5845]',`.